# remove usa results from reverse geocoding

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have currently developed a reverse geocoding google api on this site http://schoollettings.org/search-for-a-venue/ however i am having a issue with google returning a request for a usa town/city.  for example, if you search for Leigh and press enter without selecting any auto fill it defaults to Leigh, Colfax County and then returns a result of the closest school in fleetwood and shows that it is 4125 miles away, this is the same for any other towns/cities that have similar names ie boston etc. What i would like it to do is to ignore any USA addresses and only return UK based addresses.  Can this be done? if so how?

Comment: If you only want to get results from the UK, why don't you just add "UK" to you search string?

Comment: Reverse geocoding gets an address from coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a component filtering and set restriction by country.

If you use server side web service please look at
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

If you use client side geocoder service of Maps JavaScript API look at 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering

The web service request should be something like 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Leigh&components=country%3AGB&key=YOUR_API_KEY